# How to apply animation state changes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-animation

I am looking a possibility  to realize pretty pages sliding animation in my Angular 2 RC-6 application. I got as example this article
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3139-experimenting-with-conditional-enter-leave-animations-in-angular-2-rc-6.htm
But it realises internal transition changes.
I need to make it for router components, aka pages of applications.

My animations settings are next:

```
   host: {
    '[@routeAnimation]': 'true',
    '[style.display]': "'block'",
    '[class]':"'animate-jump-off'"
  },
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [
      state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
          transition('void => prev', [
            style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
            animate(300)
          ]),
          transition('prev => void', [
            animate(1000, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
          ]),
      transition('void => next', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
        animate(300)
      ]),
      transition('next => void', [
        animate(1000, style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
      ])


    ])
```

I have two transitions -next and back.
To define transition i put variable in template

```
<div class="card-container" [@routeAnimation] = "direction" >
```

and add private variable to component class.
I decided to use EventEmitter to emit new state

```
 this.emitter.subscribe(msg => {
      this.direction = (msg.direction);
      console.log(msg.direction);
    });
```

On some internal component i have link to the next page, that is launching by **goNext()** function:

```
emitter = EmitterService.get("direction");
  goNext():void {
    this.emitter.emit({'direction':'next'});
    console.log('next');
    setTimeout(() => {

        //this.router.navigate(['/questions/1']);
    }, 100)
```

I used setTimeout delay to be sure, that root component will intercept message and switch his direction state to 'next' , but it's value not applying to animation.
The same interceptor is on the next page, so on this page direction state also should be switched to 'next'.

What i have now. direction value is changing, but no animation appearing(i define direction ='none' in component constructor)

Tell me, please, what i am doing wrong, how to apply(send) direction changes to both current and next pages, or maybe there are other ways to detect routing changes on each page?

Comment: I have similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020101/ng2-animation-with-deferred-component-data-change

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a timeout, i use a CanDeactivate Guard assigned to routes, which triggers one final change detection cycle before the route change is processed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42948545/5155810